# I need to get an conditional made in postgresql for the end of the next working day

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

Well, basically I have three fields to use, the first is a date timestamp, with a creation date - for when the task is made-, the second one is a boolean that storages the conditional that verify if the end of the next working date has passed.
Example:

```
select 
      d.creation_date,
      CASE
        WHEN 
           d.creation_date IS NOT NULL
           -- conditional that verify if
           -- is a working date and
           -- has passed in a two days span
        THEN TRUE
        ELSE FALSE
      END AS limit_reached
FROM the_table;
```

In this example, if the creation date is 11/08/2021 10:00 and today is 11/11/2021 00:00, then, limit has been reached, then true, but, if the creation date still 11/08/2021 10:00 and today is 11/10/2021 23:59, the limit hasn't reach the limit yet.

EDIT: The question is, how to get the value from two days after the creation date, with the time in 23:59:59, and if this limit is greater than now() so will return false, but if is lower, will return true, meaning that the limit date was reached. But need to be only in the Bussiness Days

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The question is, how to get the value from two days after the creation date, with the time in 23:59:59, and if this limit is greater than now() so will return false, but if is lower, will return true, meaning that the limit date was reached. But need to be only in the Bussiness Days.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: CASE
        WHEN 
           d.creation_date IS NOT NULL
           AND (SELECT d.creation_date + INTERVAL '2 day') > now() THEN TRUE
        ELSE FALSE
    END AS limit_reached

Comment: What error or unexpected result did you get?

Comment: (BTW, depending on how things are set up, it may be easier and/or more efficient to write `creation_date + '2 day' > now()` as `creation_date > now() - '2 day'`; however, while that may be a component of the solution, it won't be the whole solution)

Comment: Another question you may want to think about - how do you define "working day"? Can that definition change for any particular day at short notice?

Comment: Monday to friday, only.

Comment: Well, that's a lot easier than also excluding public holidays and/or including the exceptional working Saturday and/or dealing with country-specific definitions of working week :-)

Comment: @JiříBaum, so, how could I do this, can you help me, please?

Comment: Now we're back to the beginning; what have you tried so far?